# How to use custom style when printing full-page Tabulator tables

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to print a Tabulator table using the `print()` method on the table object.

I need to set custom styling, so I'm setting the second parameter to `true`. This works in reproducing the styling of the table (with the usual HTML caveats, such as removed backgrounds).

However, I would like to use an entirely different style for printing. I tried to add rules of the following form to the stylesheet:

```
.tabulator-print-table .tabulator-headers {
    border: black 3px;
}
```

However, these do not seem to have the desired effect (in the above example, I can't see any border in the printout).

Answer (score 0):

That is totally possible, but i can see two issues with your current approach.

The first issue is that when doing whole table printing, the table is actually replaced by a standard HTML table because browsers know how to print this better, so only the classes defined in the [Print Styling List](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/style#css-print) are available, all other selection should be done using standard table elements, so to style a column header would be:

```css
.tabulator-print-table th{
   //style table column header
}
```

To style the row containing the table headers would be:

```css
.tabulator-print-table thead tr{
   //style table header row
}
```

The other issue you may be facing is if you have set the `printStyled` option to `true` in the table setup then it will be applying the existing table styles as inline styles to each of the print tables elements, so you may need to use the `!important` flag to override the inline styles:

```css
border: black 3px !important;
```